# Что может Дерево отрезков такого,чего не может Дерево Фенвика?

Tags: структуры-данных

Мне нравится Дерево Фенвика простотой реализации,но я боюсь,что сущесвуют задачи,с которыми оно справиться не может в отличии от Дерева отрезков.Вопрос:Что может Дерево отрезков такого,чего не может Дерево Фенвика?

Answer (score 1):

Я процитирую [Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0):

> Заметим, что с помощью дерева Фенвика для максимума нельзя уменьшить
>   значение, записанное в ячейке. Если требуется, чтобы структура данных
>   имела такую возможность, следует использовать дерево отрезков для
>   максимума.

И также пост с [Хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/post/112828/):

> Сравнение *(дерева Фенвика)* с деревом отрезков
>
> Преимущества:
>   — уже упомянутая простота и скорость
>   — памяти занимает O(N)
>
> Недостатки:
>   — функция должна быть обратимой, а это значит, что минимум и максимум это дерево считать не может (за исключением случаев, когда некоторыми данными мы можем пожертвовать).

Comment: собственно я больше скажу, максимум в дереве Фенвика будет только с начала. На внутреннем подотрезке найти не получится.